# Can side startup cost to build an app offset my income for tax purpose?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction

I have a full-time job and am interested in forming an LLC paying a foreign company in China to build a website or app prototype for my side startup. Can I deduct this cost against my income from my day job? What do I need to be careful about?

update: I am in the USA.

Comment: 1. That will depend on the your legislation in your country (hint) 2. Probably not

Comment: Tip: Tax questions require a country tag.

Comment: See an accountant.  In these cases they are worth what you pay in fees.

Comment: From a quick look at this IRS publication, I think you'll agree the situation of what can be deducted as an expense is...large: https://www.irs.gov/publications/p535 A lot changed in 2018, as well, so old advice may be out of date. Setting business losses/expenses against other income/employment is even more complicated, so I would also strongly suggest a CPA-equivalent to consult on the particulars, as so many little details that are hard to cover here may matter (including state income taxes, if you have them!).